# scheduler for standalone application?

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

What sheduler do you recomand for standalone java console application?

Is Quartz the only option?

I want to execute tasks every x minutes and raport the return of operation in a text file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `java.util.Timer` or `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService` for this task

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Java EE application server, you can use an EJB @Timer for this.

Answer (score 0):

Quartz is a commonly used scheduler library.  However it sounds like you need something really simple.  Can you just do something like this?  (pseudocode)

```
while (!some_termination_condition) {
   Result r = doTask();
   logResult(r);
   Thread.sleep (x_minutes*60*1000);
}
```

Comment: `Thread.sleep()` takes ms, not seconds, as the parameter. You should add a *1000 there.

Comment: thanks for the catch Bruno